# 'unable to find an inherited method for function ‘X’ for signature ‘"y"’

Tags: r, interpolation

While trying to interpolate using the idw function from R's gstat package an error keeps popping up. I got it running and fixed it somehow, but the error keeps popping up while changing small things. I might be able to solve it myself, once I understand what the error is. Can somebody elaborate on the following error?

'unable to find an inherited method for function ‘X’ for signature ‘"y"’

Thanks!

Comment: That sounds like you are using an object of wrong class when calling `idw`. Check the class of the input with `class()` and compare it to the description in the help of `idw()`. For further help you will need to post your code.

Comment: Perfect, we figured it out! Thanks! If you post your answer as an answer I will mark it as correct answer

Answer (score 5):

This can also be caused by namespace conflicts. For example, I had both the `hash` and `data.table` libraries loaded, and they both have `copy` functions. Running

```
> copy(DT)
```

on a `data.table` gives `Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable) : unable to find an inherited method for function ‘copy’ for signature ‘"data.table"’`. The solution is to specify the namespace:

```
> data.table::copy(DT)
```